# Commands for SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I was wondering why are commands such as '''CREATE TABLE''' written in a docstring instead of it being a method like db.create_table()?

Comment: What you're referring to as a docstring is actually a multi-line string, it's just a convenient way of writing long strings in Python (although it's sometimes used for docstrings).

Comment: and if you don't have ORM database, you are not able to use methods like `db.create_table()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because Python's SQLite driver is just a thin layer over the SQLite library and basically just passes the commands to SQLite.

Since SQLite uses SQL as its querying and data definition language, one uses SQL to create tables and fetch data from the db. It is sometimes most convenient to just hardcode the SQL commands, although using some other library to specify the schema and automatically generate SQL statements is also possible. Take a look at https://www.sqlalchemy.org/ if you're interested.